# Adjusting x-labels on histogram

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, analytics

I am plotting a histogram of house prices with a line of code as : 
plt.hist(housing['price'])

However, on x-axis, the labels / text of the labels ( prices such as 10000,20000 are intersecting with each other). Can anyone tell how to solve the issue ?

plt.hist(housing['price'])

Comment: Could you show the histogram and the code created it so we can help you figure out what should be modified?

Comment: you can use `rotate` in the histogram to avoid intersection of labels